# Github Action: Split Long Command into Multiple Lines

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I have a Github action command that is really long:

```
name: build

on: [push]

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v1
            - name: Install Prerequisites
              run: |
                sudo apt-get update
                sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends "a very very long list of prerequisites"
```

May I know whether it is possible to split the long command into multiple lines for better readability? I have tried the separator '' but it does not work.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

I have a multi line command using backslash to separate the lines as follows:

```
- name: Configure functions
  run: |
    firebase functions:config:set \
      some.key1="${{ secrets.SOME_KEY_1 }}" \
      some.key2="${{ secrets.SOME_KEY_2 }}" \
    ...
```

Note the preceding '|' character, and make sure the subsequent lines after the first one are indented (tabulated).

Comment: This is the correct answer and would be a better accepted answer. The backslashes work the same as a multiline command in bash. (I'd recommend a hanging indent for readability though.)

Comment: Does anyone know since when this is possible? (I think it was not possible when I wrote my answer but I fully agree with that answer being accepted, now)

Comment: @dan1st I also do not think this is possible by the time I asked this, but it seems that Github people have added the support for backslash.

Comment: I don't know how did it work previously for anyone, but adding a backslash does not work right now with GitHub Actions. This shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: I confirm: this does not work on GitHub Actions as of now. You need to use ">" instead of "I" (see other answers)

Comment: It seems to work but it doesn't fail on any errors, same with > also.. so it becomes kind of pointless..

Comment: @mcserep in fact this answer works for me and solution with ">" doesn't. When I used ">", the second line was treated like another command

Comment: Use ">". "|" doesn't work anymore.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to get rid of the "\" characters at the end.

Comment: It works for the moment. Make sure you have a whitespace before the backslash, too.

Comment: this one works for me, the '>' one doesn't work for me

Comment: This doesn't work. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65808412/3420114

Comment: You can use `>` to split *a single command* on more lines, `|` allow to write more command in the same run, but one command each line, where you have to use `\` to split the same command on more lines aware to put lines of same command indented once to enhance readability.

Comment: The probable reason **why this does not work for others** is because you guys might be **combining all the commands into one**. \ is a continuation so in @Mike's example that is actually just one command.

Comment: `>` worked for me for a single command, but if I still want multiple commands I could get `|` to work, at least not for the default windows runner using PowerShell... may try the backtick for PowerShell itself...

Comment: Works well for me, no clue why it doesn't work for others...

Comment: This works like a charm. It would be really interesting if they who can't get it to work this way posted their code snippet.

Comment: This originally didn't work for me, but after some playing around, I was able to get it. For those who are struggling, double check every line is ended with exactly one whitespace and one backslash. I had a line which had an additional whitespace after the backslash, which caused it to not work. Hope this helps!

Comment: I confirm it works. And can still put multiple commands in one step: after each finished command no \ and start the next command with the indention of the previous command. This turns many commands into beautiful readable lines of code. ❤️

Answer (score 158):

You can use the YAML **folded style** with `>` which is supported by GitHub Actions.

For example,

```yaml
run: >
  xvfb-run
  ./mvnw -f my/pom.xml
  clean verify
  -DskipTests
```

newlines will be replaced with spaces so the above is equivalent to

```yaml
run: xvfb-run ./mvnw -f my/pom.xml clean verify -DskipTests
```

Comment: Also see https://yaml-multiline.info/ to play around with the different scalar / chomping styles.

Comment: This works, thank you! Important note: per yml spec, white space is important here, so any extra tabs before the lines will cause problems.

Comment: It seems to work but it doesn't fail on any errors, same with | also.. so it becomes kind of pointless..

Comment: @JohnnyOshika Thank you for that comment! It cleared a long standing misunderstanding for me.

Comment: Just a quick note about this being for the default shell. For example, my YML file had some bits running R code with `shell: Rscript {0}`, and line breaking in those cases don't need any special characters (just like in R).

Comment: As @JohnnyOshika points out, white space is critical here (learned it the hard way). If a line starts with extra spaces, the line will be ignored. So make sure all lines start at the same column.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be necessary to strip preceding whitespace from lines in Github actions anymore, at least when using `pwsh`. Tested on Ubuntu/Windows/MacOS.

Answer (score 102):

Going to share this in since it has not been mentioned.

You can use:

- `|` called a `Literal Block Scalar` which preserves new lines and trailing spaces
- `>` called a `Folded Block Scalar` which converts new lines into spaces
- plain old strings, either unquoted, single-quoted or double-quoted

Additionally, you can append a block chomping indicator, `-`, `+` or none. which will alter the newlines at the end of the block.

these are the block chomping definitions

- `-` is called `strip` removes newlines at the end
- `+` is called `keep` keeps all newlines at the end
- default behavior is keeping a single newline at the end

I found the site [yaml-multiline.info](https://yaml-multiline.info/) useful for understanding how yaml strings are interpreted.

For my use case, I ended up doing the following:

```
run: >-
  for i in $(find . -type f -name "*.log");
  do
   echo "File: ${i} \n";
   cat $i;
   printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -;
  done
```

Comment: What does the hyphen in `>-` do?

Comment: @silkfire According to the linked website, it appears to strip newlines from the end of the block, so that there's not an extra trailing \n at the end.

Comment: That said, this is not supported by GitHub Actions: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/418

Comment: It's supported now https://github.com/sparks-baird/self-driving-lab-demo/actions/runs/3639637826/workflow

Comment: What is the difference between `>` and `>-`?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg, as I mentioned in my earlier comment, adding the hyphen (i.e., `>-`) strips the last newline character, while not including it (i.e., `>`) includes a newline at the end of the string.

Answer (score 34):

The above answers all had pieces, but this is what worked for me in a github composite action. It should work in a regular workflow too.

As @lorenzo-bettini said, if you want everything to be on one line, use what @Josue Alexander Ibarra called a `Folded Block Scalar`.

```yaml
run: >
  xvfb-run
  ./mvnw -f my/pom.xml
  clean verify
  -DskipTests
```

> newlines will be replaced with spaces so the above is equivalent to

```yaml
run: xvfb-run ./mvnw -f my/pom.xml clean verify -DskipTests
```

If you want new lines to be preserved, use what @Josue Alexander Ibarra called a `Literal Block Scalar`.

```yaml
run: |
  FILE=./package.json
  if test -f "$FILE"
  then
    echo "$FILE exists."
  else
    echo "File does not exist"
  fi
```

When you do a multi-line run, though, you have to make sure you indent correctly, otherwise `step` will think that `shell: bash` is part of the `run: |` string.

**WRONG:**

```yaml
  steps:
    - run: |
      FILE=./package.json
      if test -f "$FILE"
      then
        echo "$FILE exists."
      else
        echo "File does not exist"
      fi
      shell: bash
```

**RIGHT:**

```yaml
  steps:
    - run: |
        FILE=./package.json
        if test -f "$FILE"
        then
          echo "$FILE exists."
        else
          echo "File does not exist"
        fi
      shell: bash
```

Comment: Important: for the '>' block, make sure each line has the same indentation.

Answer (score 12):

At the time this answer was originally written, this was not possible using backslashes. See the accepted answer on how to do it now.

---

As far as I know, GitHub Actions does not support that.

However, you can use environment variables for that.

For example, this script splits your command in 3 lines of code and executes it as one line.

```
steps:
  - name: Install Prerequisites
    run: |
      sudo apt-get update
      bash -c "$line1 $line2 $line3"
    env:
    - line1='sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends '
    - line2='a very very long list'
    - line3='of prerequisites'
```

It creates the environment variables `line1`, `line2` and `line3` and concats and executes them in a bash session.

Comment: `$line1 $line2 $line3` directly works without requiring another bash

Answer (score 4):

Note also the [join](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#join) and [format](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#format) functions for expressions:

```
HELLO_WORLD = ${{ join('Hello', 'world!') }}
HELLO_WORLD = ${{ format('{{Hello {0}}}', 'World') }}
```

Presumably these could be combined with env variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to do it, it will work with Github Actions:

```
name: build

on: [push]

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
        steps:
            - name: Install Prerequisites
              uses: actions/checkout@v1
              run: >
                sudo apt-get update && 
                sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends
                "a very very long 
                list of prerequisites"
```

alternative to the `&&` is to split that in several steps, like:

```
name: build

on: [push]

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
        steps:
            - name: Install Prerequisites - checkout phase
              uses: actions/checkout@v1

            - name: Install Prerequisites - update phase
              run: sudo apt-get update

            - name: Install Prerequisites - install phase
              run: >
                sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends
                "a very very long
                list of prerequisites"
```